# How to check network availability on Honeycomb?

Tags: android, networking, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm trying to check if a simple connection is available on my honeycomb app. I've tried 2 different versions of the function:

```
    public boolean networkAvailable() {
     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
```

and

```
    private boolean networkAvailable(){
    ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return activeNetwork != null;
}
```

Neither of these work on my Honeycomb tablet though, they crash wherever I try to call them. Is there a particular way of doing this on 3.2 or...what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. You can even differentiate the type of network available. Make sure you have the following permissions declared in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

```
public void checkkStatus()
 {
 final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
 this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
 connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

 final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =
 connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

 if( wifi.isAvailable() ){
 Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 else if( mobile.isAvailable() ){
 Toast.makeText(this, "Mobile 3G " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 else
 {Toast.makeText(this, "No Network " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it works great! Thanks a million for taking the time to answer me! This is a very useful piece of code, I'm saving to my snippets!

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
   public boolean isOnline() {
         ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
   }
```

Comment: Same thing...I'm using a Dell Streak 7". Could this be particular to my hardware..?